# Select screen in detached screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

In `screen` there is a `kill` command, which kills the current window. This command can be sent even to a detached `screen` session by running:

```
screen -S SessionName -X kill
```

This works to kill the current window only. To kill any other window, it appears the only way is to first switch to that window and then kill it. The `select` command allows switching between windows in a `screen` session. Typing the following while attached to a `screen` session will select the window named `foo`.

```
^A:select foo
```

However, when not attached to the session, it appears the `select` command has no effect. Running the following two commands will kill the current window, rather than the window named `foo` (unless of course that is the active window).

```
screen -S SessionName -X select foo
screen -S SessionName -X kill
```

I have verified that this occurs even if I attach and detach from the session before attempting to select a window (a known workaround for some other screen quirks).

Comment: Did you omit quotes around `"select foo"`?

Comment: I've tried three variations in quoting. None of them work better than the others. `"-X select foo"` produces an error (expected). `-X "select foo"` produces no effect. `-X select "foo"` produces no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `-p` to select the window, numbered from 0, eg

```
screen -S SessionName -p 1 -X kill
```

Comment: It seems that although the screen `man` page says that the `kill` command operates on the current window, it in fact requires the `-p` flag to select the window by title.